# Aggregation: adding fields to mongo document from another object

Tags: mongodb

I have an array which looks like this

```
const posts = [{ _id: '1', viewsCount: 52 }, ...]
```

Which corresponds to mongodb documents in `posts` collection

```
{
  _id: '1',
  title: 'some title',
  body: '....',
}, ...
```

I want to perform an aggregation which would result in documents fetched from the `posts` collection to have a `viewsCount` field. I'm not sure how I should form my aggregation pipeline:

```
[
  { $match: {} },
  { $addFields: { viewsCount: ?? } }
]
```

**UPDATE**

So far the following code almost does the trick:

```
[
    { $match: {} },
    { $addFields: { viewsCount: { $arrayElemAt: [posts, { $indexOfArray: [ posts, '$_id' ] } ] } } },
]
```

But `viewsCount` in this case turns to be an object, so I guess I need to add `$project`

**UPDATE**

I've found out one possible solution which is to use `$addFields` stage twice - overriding the first `viewsCount`

```
[
    { $match: {} },
    { $addFields: { viewsCount: { $arrayElemAt: [posts, { $indexOfArray: [ posts, '$_id' ] } ] } } },
    { $addFields: { viewsCount: '$viewsCount.viewsCount' } }
]
```

But is there a better/more concise solution?

**UPDATE**

This pipeline actually works correct:

```
[
    { $match: {} },
    { $addFields: { viewsCount: { $arrayElemAt: [posts, { $indexOfArray: [ postsIds, '$_id' ] } ] } } },
    { $addFields: { viewsCount: '$viewsCount.viewsCount' } }
]
```

I have updated the second stage by replacing `posts` with `postsIds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a more concise solution (one-stage) you can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) operator which lets you to define temporary variable that can be then used inside your expression, try:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { 
        viewsCount: {
            $let: {
                vars: { viewsCountObj: { $arrayElemAt: [posts, { $indexOfArray: [ posts, '$_id' ] } ] } },
                in: "$$viewsCountObj.viewsCount"
            }
        } }
    }
])
```

Comment: seems like your solution does not solve the problem (as well as mine). Aggregated documents all have same viewsCount value

Comment: I guess the problem steams from `$indexOfArray`

Comment: You can try  `{ $indexOfArray: [ posts.map(p => p._id), '$_id' ] }`